# Javascript with Spring not send data from field

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, neo4j

I am new to Javascript and spring coding.

It is a web app working on Spring framework and with frontend with Mustache template with jQuery.

What I want add new form field (`id="exampleTextarea"`) to the working example. I think this problem is on JavaScript part because checking in java code back null on added field value.

Anybody can direct me what things I am missing?

> In post.html I added new field, smile duplicate existed on.

```
  <!-- add textarea in form-->      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleTextarea" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Textarea</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control  input-sm" id="exampleTextarea" name="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

> In graphstory.js  javascript file was changed functions.
>   addContent(),  contentformToJSON(), on
>
> .on()

$('#contentAddEdit').on('click', 'a#addcontent', function() {
    console.log( $( this ).text() );

```
if ( $("#contentform").is(":visible") ) {
    $("#addcontent").text('Add Content');
    $("#contentform")[0].reset();
    $("#contentform").hide();
    $("#btnSaveContent").text('Add Content XXX');
}else{
    $("#contentform").show();
    $("#addcontent").text("Cancel");
    $("#btnSaveContent").text('Add Content');

}
return false;
```

});

> addContent()

```
function addContent(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/posts/add',
        dataType: "json",
        data: contentformToJSON(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

            $('#content').prepend('<tr><td><a href="'+data.url+'" target="_blank">'+data.title+'</a>  
                    <br/>tags: '+data.tagstr+' ::  
                    //text fild
                    <br/>Textarea: '+data.exampleTextarea+' ::  
                        Posted by '+data.userNameForPost+' at <a href="/viewpost/'+data.contentId+'">'+data.timestampAsStr+'</a><br/></td></tr>');

            $('#title').val("");
            $('#url').val("");

            $("#contentform").hide();
            $("#addcontent").text('Add Content');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('add contnt error: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

> contentformToJSON()

```
function contentformToJSON() {

/*  added text fild*/
if($("#tagstr").length == 0 | $("#exampleTextarea").length == 0) {
    return JSON.stringify({"title": $('#title').val(), "url": $('#url').val() });
}if else($("#tagstr").length == 0){
    return JSON.stringify({"title": $('#title').val(), "url": $('#url').val(), "exampleTextarea": $('#exampleTextarea').val() });
}if else($("#exampleTextarea").length == 0){
    return JSON.stringify({"title": $('#title').val(), "url": $('#url').val(), "tagstr": $('#tagstr').val() });
    }else{
return JSON.stringify({"title": $('#title').val(), "url": $('#url').val(), "tagstr": $('#tagstr').val(),"exampleTextarea": $('#exampleTextarea').val() });
}
}
```

I changes the code  only in two files post.html and graphstory.js here code from files.

Here is  post.html

```
<div class="global/base-app"><!-- add textarea in form-->       
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleTextarea" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Textarea</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control  input-sm" id="exampleTextarea" name="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Try to narrow down to describe the specific problem you're having, including only the relevant code; instead of dumping your entire source, try putting your code on a site like http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io and include a link.

Comment: Don't CODEDUMP!

Comment: @Sensei James Thank for link but I don't think it help  because my case specific for Spring not only for front end coder.  Maybe problem is in structure of project .                                                                                   All the code I posted here  have comment  inside for fast finding the changed function  but maybe edit can help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a cure for this stack. It was made from html tag `<textarea>`. Exchange it with `<input>` works fine.